# VBScript function is giving errors. Please help?

Tags: vbscript

```
Public Function BinarySearch(userNameString, switchPosition) As Boolean
    If Right(LCase(userNameString), 8) = "lastname" Then
        If Left(LCase(userNameString), 5) = "admin" Or Left(LCase(userNameString, 7) = "firstname" Then
            If StrComp(switchIsOn(switchPosition), "1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ' Verify the user is admin lastname or firstname lastname and switch is on
                Return True
            Else
                ' Verify the user is admin lastname or firstname lastname and switch is off
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            ' Users last name is lastname
            Return False
        End If
    Else
        ' Not lastname
        Return False
    End If    
End Function
```

When I run it, I get an error on the first line Public Function...

What I get is 
"Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot type in VBScript so:

Public Function BinarySearch(userNameString, switchPosition) <s>As Boolean</s>

Comment: Thanks The return statement is also giving problems. How do you return a value?

Comment: Use the name of the function `BinarySearch=False`

Answer (score 0):

In vbscript everything is variant , no need to type your variables.
Assingng your return value to the name of your function:
BinarySearch = false
You name your function binarysearch and then you do a textcompare ?